# How to get final result data from a function

Tags: javascript, function, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I've been trying to make function(see bellow) to work. If i call this function in my test like this:

```
 test.meta({ CID: 'C67', type: TestType.Critical }).timeouts({
    pageLoadTimeout: 5000,})(
    'Test to GetData',
    async (t:TestController) => {
      // When
const result  = getData.getFinalData()
const finalResult = JSON.stringify(result)
console.log(finalResult)
  })
```

In the log i get empty result:
Case Discovery
{}

But if i do console.log(data) inside the function, i do get the proper data.
So i just want to know how to get that data. As I will need later to use it for my test.

I was intending to use it like this:

const randomCaseId  = finalResult[getRandomInt(1000)].caseId.toString()

```
public async getFinalData () {

    fetch(TOKEN_API, {
      method: 'post',
      body: new URLSearchParams(details),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
   })
   .then((res: { json: () => any; }) => res.json())
   .then((json: any) => { 
    const token = (json.accessToken.toString())
    console.log(token),
    fetch(DATA_API, {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}})
     .then((res: { json: () => any; }) => res.json())
     .then((json:any)=>{
       const data =  JSON.stringify(json)
       return data;
     }
     )
  })}
```

Comment: why are you stringifying the `data`? JSON is far less usable than an object. And then you attempt to stringify JSON you assume would be returned. Not sure you understand JSON ...

Comment: since `getFinalData` doesn't return anything, and it is `async` you'll never get anything but a promise that resolves to `undefined` when calling that function. 1. Why is `getFinalData` taged `async` since you never use `await`. 2. to access the result of calling the function, you'll either need to `await` it, or use `.then` on the result

Comment: use `const result  = await getData.getFinalData()` in `async (t:TestController) => {` - but make sure `getFinalData` actually returns what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- When you return a value inside the function which you've passed to `then`, it would not be returned as the value of the outer function
- `getFinalData` is a `async` so it would return a promise
- `getFinalData` is returning a promise but you never pass a value as the resolved data

You can use following code, which wait for the response:

```
test.meta({
    CID: 'C67',
    type: TestType.Critical
}).timeouts({
    pageLoadTimeout: 5000,
})(
    'Test to GetData',
    async (t: TestController) => {
        // When
        const result = await getData.getFinalData()
        const finalResult = JSON.stringify(result)
        console.log(finalResult)
    })
```

And also make sure to wait for the fetch and return the resolved value:

```
public async getFinalData() {
    const res = await fetch(TOKEN_API, {
            method: 'post',
            body: new URLSearchParams(details),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
        })
    const json = await res.json();
    const token = (json.accessToken.toString())
    console.log(token);
    const response = await fetch(DATA_API, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                });
    return response.json();    
}
```

Comment: to be honest, I don't think any of the JSON.stringify are required ... with this code, if the result were the OBJECT `{hello: "world"}` then the finalResult would be ... wait for it `\"{\\\"hello\\\":\\\"world\\\"}\"` - even if the original result was a sting `world`, the final result would be `\"\\\"world\\\"\"`

Comment: @Bravo right, I totally forgot about it! Updated

Comment: one more ... `return await response.json();`  can be `return response.json();` because of how promises work

Comment: @Bravo I know, but this way is a bit cleaner!

Comment: Guys, thank you very very much for a help. Please understand I am not a developer, only learning. I am automation engineer that just trying to automate our web app.

Answer (score 2):

since `getFinalData` doesn't return anything, and it is `async` you'll never get anything but a promise that resolves to `undefined` when calling that function.

Why is `getFinalData` tagged `async` since you never use `await`. I would use async/await for simple code, rather than the .then chain you are using

To access the result of calling that function, you'll either need to `await` it, or use `.then` on the result - since the calling funciton is `async`, use `await`

Rewrite your code like

```
test.meta({ CID: 'C67', type: TestType.Critical })
.timeouts({pageLoadTimeout: 5000,})('Test to GetData', async (t:TestController) => {
    // When
    const finalResult  = await getData.getFinalData();
    console.log(finalResult)
})
```

and

```
public async getFinalData () {
    const tokenres = await fetch(TOKEN_API, {
        method: 'post',
        body: new URLSearchParams(details),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    });
    const tokendata = await tokenres.json();
    const token = tokendata.accessToken.toString();
    console.log(token);
    const res = await fetch(DATA_API, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}
        });
    // ** see note below, don't do the next two lines like this
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}
```

This code uses async/await properly, and doesn't stringify the data into JSON, twice!

Also, note

```
const data = await res.json();
return data;
```

can be the single line

```
return res.json();
```

Because that's how promises work